# Openlayers CQL filter to show feature points but not remove previous?

Tags: javascript, jquery, openlayers, cql, openlayers-6

I am trying to select all customers from my list to show on the map using cql filter IN function.

the problem is that i am selecting customers asynchronously 500 hundred after 500 hundred when cql filter gets the next 500 it removes previous 500 from the map.

what can i do to that cql filter does not remove the previous 500 and show the next 500 hundred with it?

```
  let points = [];

 $("#selectAllCustomers").on("change", async function () {
if (this.checked) {
  dataload.classList.remove("loading-finish");
  setTimeout(async () => {
    let checkedProducts = $("input[name='productInput']:checked");
    let checkedProductsIds = [];
    checkedProducts.each(function () {
      let ids = $(this).attr("id");
      checkedProductsIds.push(ids);
    });
    let customerCheckedIds = [];

    let customercheckboxlength = $(
      "input[name='customer-input']:visible"
    ).not(":checked");

    if (customercheckboxlength.length > 0) {
      for (let i = 0; i < customercheckboxlength.length; i++) {
        let ch = customercheckboxlength[i];
        let chid = customercheckboxlength[i].id;
        ch.checked = true;
        customerCheckedIds.push(chid.slice(4));
```

> ```
>  let point = chid.slice(4);
>
>  points.push(parseInt(point));
> ```

```
        if (i == 499) {
          break;
        }
      }
      // console.log(customerCheckedIds, checkedProductsIds);
      wmsPoint.setVisible(true);
   
  

 //pointsLayer.updateParams({ CQL_FILTER: null });
```

> ```
>       pointsLayer.updateParams({
>         CQL_FILTER: `idShop in ${points}`,
>       });
> ```

```
      if (customercheckboxlength.length > 0) {
        $(this).prop("checked", true).trigger("change");
      }
    } else {
      dataload.classList.add("loading-finish");
    }
  }, 3000);
} else {

  points = [];
  wmsPoint.setVisible(false);
  pointsLayer.updateParams({
    CQL_FILTER: `idShop in ${points}`,
  });
  $("input[name='customer-input']:visible").each(function () {
    this.checked = false;
    // $(this).trigger("change");
  });
}
```

});

as you can see that points is the array where i am storing every 500 id s of my customer shops.

on every loop 500 hundred id add to the points array but when points array has 1000 or 1500 ids it does not work it gives cors error .

Comment: If you are getting the points as a WMS image you could use tile WMS so you have fewer points per request.  Alternatively use WFS with a vector layer.

Comment: Yes i am using tilewms layer to show points on map.